# How can i stop hearing mediaplayer on call?

Tags: android, audio, function-call

I thought that android automatically stops sound from other sources than call . But i have seen in a program i'm developing that it only put it too low .

Anyway to solve this problem? Any OnCall event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go  through below link and check this **Handling the AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY Intent**.It has a nice ex-planation how to handle media player when call came.

[Refer Bottom part of this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Comment: How did you find it?its very nice and easy to implement.Hope you will do it :)

Comment: I'm having problems implementing it on an extend activity . It tells me : The type BroadcastReceiver cannot be a superinterface of MainActivity; a superinterface must be an interface

Comment: make one seperate class for broadcast and register it in manifest then it will automatically start for more detail go to android developer receiver tutorial